# using malloc for block of structs

Tags: c, arrays, list, linked-list, malloc

I am trying to allocate a block of memory, and store a list of structures without using multiple mallocs for each... this is just a generic example, I don't have the original code I was working with earlier, but this is the general idea, but my problem was that I was getting heap corruption when other parts of my code executed after the InitPoints() function call.  I don't know what part of my code is illegal, but I suspect it is in the for loop of the InitPoints() function.    I am trying to use this as table, then I can create additional tables of defined size if I ran out of memory and link them together... so kind of like a dynamic expanding array if that makes any sense.

```
typedef struct Tb{
   POINT points;
   POINT *next;
 } TABLE;

typedef struct Pt{
   int x;
   int y;
}POINT;

POINT *mypoints;

int main() {
   int size = 10;
   int i = 0;
   mypoints = InitPoints(size);

   for(i=0; i < size; i++)
   {
      printf("mypoint [%d] = (%d,%d)\n",i, mypoints->x, mypoints->y);
      mypoints = mypoints + sizeof(POINT);
   }
  // some other code...
  // i.e. createThread(....)

   return 0;
}

POINT* InitPoints(int size)
{
   POINT *tmp;
   POINT *orig;
   int a = 10;
   int b = 1000;
   orig = (POINT*) malloc (sizeof(POINT) * size);
   if(orig == NULL)
      return NULL;

   tmp = orig;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      tmp->x = a++;
      tmp->y = b++;
      tmp = tmp + sizeof(POINT);
   }
return orig;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
mypoints = mypoints + sizeof(POINT);
```

You should review pointer arithmetic in C. Just use:

```
mypoints += 1; /* or something similar */
```

(There is a similar problem in your InitPoints function)

Here's one referemce:

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html

Comment: thanks, and I am on crack for trying to do this, or do people actually use this?  I don't want to use a simple linked list to avoid maintaining a list.  I know most of the time I will only have a small number of elements to work with... say 10, but in case i need more space I will just allocate another 10 and so on...

Comment: No, it's not particularly bad. Don't be careful about your pointer arithmetic!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
tmp = tmp + sizeof(POINT);
```

It should be

```
++tmp;
```

The latter says to increment the pointer by one element; since it points to the structure, it increments by the size of the structure.   The original code instead increments by *n* elements where *n* is the number of bytes in the structure.  For example, if int is 32-bits, it will advanced by 8 elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I would do it

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    orig[i].x = a++;
    orig[i].y = b++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, adding an integer to a POINT* pointer advances the pointer not by that number of bytes, but by that number of POINT structures.

You have two places in your code where you add `sizeof(POINT)` to your pointer.  Instead you should just add 1.