# how to create a linked list of tables, a table represents a group of elements

Tags: arrays, list, dynamic, linked-list, malloc

what I am trying to do is represented in  [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106828/using-malloc-for-block-of-structs) with code.

Basically I need to keep in memory a table of elements (structs), there's no fixed number of elements that can exist, but it is small, but I still can't use an array.

And I don't want to use a linked list of elements because I don't want to keep adding and deleting elements everytime I need to change anything.

Instead what I want to do is allocate a chunk of memory with a single malloc, that chunk of memory will be large enough for say, 100 elements, and if in the rare case that I need more, I can allocate another chunk of 100 elements and link it to the original....

Is this a good idea?  is there a name for this kind of structure?  it's kinda of like dynamic expanding array?   Do people actually use this? or I am just on crack?  if this is bad idea, what do you recommend using instead?

Thanks

```
typedef struct Tb{
   POINT points;
   POINT *next;
} TABLE;

typedef struct Pt{
   int x;
   int y;
}POINT;


POINT *mypoints;
int a = 10;
int b = 1000;

mypoints = (POINT*) malloc (100 * sizeof(POINT));

for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
    mypoints->x = a++;
    mypoints->y = b++;
    ++mypoints;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such allocation schemes have been used everywhere from the early Unix file system to Python's internal list allocation.

Code on!

Comment: ok thanks, what is it called? any term I can use to find some other real world examples on google, perhaps some sample code?

would it be a bad/good idea to add a POINT* next element to my POINT struct?

Comment: @emge It is called a heap if you track it with a list or tree. A Vector if you have you have a dynamic array

Answer (score 1):

This is a common data structure, that I've seen in some places named as "linked list of tables".

I'm assuming you are looking for a C++ answer since your code is in C++. The C++ standards does not impose a specific data structure for its containers. However, the specification kind of forces the compiler builders to use a specific data structure, since it it is the most appropriate to fulfill the specifications.

In C++, this is the case for the std::deque, which typically uses the data structure you describe above. To quote the documentation on the subject : *"As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays"*. See : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque